# What do you call the two components resulting from filtering?

Tags: word-request

Suppose I am given the numbers from 1 to 9:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

I filter out the prime numbers:

> 2 3 5 7  (A)

and I am left with:

> 1 4 6 8 9  (B)

What do you call (A) and (B) with respect to the filtering?

I am not sure if "filtered out" refers to the component which was removed, or the component which was retained.

Answer (score 4):

Mathematicians use the term **residue** for anything left over, which fits nicely with the concept of **filtering**. I would call (B) the residue and (A) the **filtrate** in your example. The residue in this case, by the way, is the union of the positive composites and the unit 1.

Wikipedia

- [Residue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue)
- [Remainder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder)

Oxford Dictionaries

- [Residue](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/residue)

Often also called the remainder, which is listed as a synonym for residue at Oxford dictionaries, but the more usual expression in Mathematics is to call it a residue.

Also, from Mathworld

- [Residue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue)

Comment: residue is used for *anything* left over, the examples given at Mathworld are just examples.

Comment: I'd remembered the word _residue_ from chemistry class, but didn't remember the word from set theory. Thanks for the refresher!

Answer (score 1):

"Filtered out" would refer A as it was the set that was removed.

(B) I would call the set "that remains" or something similar. There may be a better word for (B)

Comment: For (B) you could use "remaining numbers"